# R: colorized R output difference between Mac and Ubuntu

Tags: r, linux, macos, ubuntu

I am using R package [colorout](https://github.com/jalvesaq/colorout):

> colorizes R output when running in a Unix (e.g. Linux and OS X)
>   terminal emulator

I am running it on two different computers:

- macOS Sierra (R version 3.3.2)
- Ubuntu 14.04.5 (R version 3.3.2)

On these two computers I get different `colorized` output (see example images bellow).

**My question is** - how can I "normalize" terminal colour options between two platforms to get the same result?

**Mac result:**[image]
**Ubuntu result:**[image: Ubuntu]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both terminals must have same colour options.
In Ubuntu `~/.bashrc` I had:

```
export TERM=xterm-256color
```

I added same line to OS X `~/bash_profile`